# Android how to save preferences and In-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, sharedpreferences

I have an IAB that when the purchase succeeded it calls this bit of code :

```
private void updateInterface() {

    if (mIsPremium) {

        displayAd(false);
        savePreferences(null);
    } else {

        displayAd(true);

    }
}
```

And the savepreferences i have this :

```
    private void savePreferences(String String) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.ANTI_ADS_KEY, "prde");
    editor.commit();
    editor.clear();
}
```

In the utils i have this :

```
public static boolean hasValidKey() {
    SharedPreferences settings = CustomApplication.getAppContext()
            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_FILE,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String key = settings.getString(Constants.ANTI_ADS_KEY,
            Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE);
    if (key != null
            && ((key.trim().startsWith("pR+") && key.trim()
                    .endsWith("de@p")) || (key.trim().startsWith("pr") && key
                    .trim().endsWith("de")))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So is all the code above looks right to you ?

Comment: This question does not have clear direction. Consider rephrasing it to be more specific besides, "Does this look right to you".

Answer (score 0):

You should not call this:

```
editor.clear();
```

It would clear all your committed changes.